# IntelliJ IDEA 2017 - Missing Debug window

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

My Intellij Debugger window went missing and I can't find any resources on how to get it back, the closest think I can get to my problem is a missing console window but that doesn't help. So I'm hoping someone here can help me retrieve it.

This pic shows a normal Intellij IDE (that I got from my friend) that shows the tab that's missing for me (in red) and the area in which this tab normally shows (in yellow).

[image]

And this pic shows my IDE with the missing Debugger window.

[image]

I also opened Intellij's help dialogue which claims that the window will show up when your code hits a break point but that didn't do it for me either.

Comment: Does it happen only for Grails, or for the plain Java Application Run/Debug configurations as well?

Comment: No, I tried a Java application too now. Exactly the same situation as with Grails, the only (irrelevant looking) difference is the title bar (on the second pic in my question the bit that says 'Debug <Grails icon> Grails: gomelo' has been replaced with 'Debug <unknown icon> Main'.

Comment: Try removing `.idea/workspace.xml` file. If it doesn't help, remove [IDE settings directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) to start with the defaults.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the "restore layout" button at the left toolbar of the debugger toolwindow

[image]

Comment: Give this man a beer. I haven't been able to figure this out since asking the question and you just now saved the day. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Showing a tool window:
"Choose View" | "Tool Windows" | "Debug Tool Window" in the main menu.

It as simple as that.
There are multiple other things you can try, look here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html#show

For example reset your Tool Windows:

You can return to the default workspace layout by choosing "Window" | "Restore Default Layout" (Shift+F12).

Comment: I _think_ the OP can see the Debug tool window. If I have understood the question correctly then the issue is that he cannot see the `Debugger` panel **within** the `Debug` tool window.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right @glitch . I wonder if the `layout restore` or `debugger toolbar restore` works.

Comment: Yup, what Glitch said. So when I go to View > Tool Windows there is no 'Debug Tool Window'  (I can edit a screen shot of this menu in, if you'd like?) although it does have just a 'Debug' option but that just opens up the whole bottom window thing (shown in yellow in my question) without the actual debugger panel. I also tried resetting the tool windows but that just closed the directory view and bottom window thing and when I opened it back up nothing changed. I also checked out the link you posted with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

To enable the debug window
Click on View -> Tool Windows -> Debug

Or press (Alt+5)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the specific question asked but a possible solution to *My debug window has disappeared!*. My situation was actually with Android Studio but should apply elsewhere.

My symptoms were:

- I use multiple monitors and after a system crash my debug window
  vanished.
- Before the crash my debug window was in window mode on a separate
  monitor. After the crash it was gone.
- There was no `Debug` tab showing on the main window.
- The `Debug` entry in the `View` menu was greyed.

The solution that finally worked was to set a break-point at a location I knew the code would hit, debug my project and make it hit the break-point. The `Debug` window magically appeared.

Remember to reposition the window correctly before exiting.

Comment: I second that your answer here is more useful. It helped me but I also had to restart IntelliJ IDEA (version 2019.3) and then the trick with break-point made the window reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try button on the right (there should be debugger, console....)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to Restore default layout in console/debugger screen. Its give in image please do check.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Remove the dev option from `run/debug configurations` from **Command line**.

Answer (score 0):

You would have undocked, just look for "dock" sign, click on it.
Now debugger will restored to default view
[image]